# Node.js on Linux endpoint works with 'api//method' but not 'api/method'

Tags: node.js, linux, apache

I am running a node js server on linux aws ec2. I am trying to create a subdomain so I can run my node rest api at `http://api.domain.com`.

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /server.js
</IfModule>
```

Everything works great, but when I try and hit `http://api.domain.com/method`, it bombs out. However `http://api.domain//method` (**emphasis on the double //)** works fine. If I just hit `http://api.domain/` I get the expected 'Cannot Get /' error message.

Also, `http://ip-address:3000/method` works just fine

I'm assuming I need some extra entry in my `.htaccess` file or something but I can't find anything out there...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I got it working by wrapping the proxies in double quotes:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

After running `sudo service httpd restart` everything worked as expected.